# Z3 bitvecs to Int and back

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I have the following code:

```
from z3 import *

a0 = Int('a0')
a1 = Int('a1')
a2 = Int('a2')
v1 = BitVec('v1',32)

s.add(v1 ==  ((a0 + a1) >> 31) >> 30)
s.add(((v1 + a2) & 3) - v1 == 1)
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'ArithRef' and 'int'
```

I understand the problem, z3 can't handle implied conversion like native python can (i.e. `45 >> 3` is directly converted to `5`). However, I need my variables `a_i` to be Ints. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `BV2Int` and `Int2BV`. See here:

https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a7954eb7ea27b3972070ac9eb6f5946a2

https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#ac516cd29fb1da802c07a51b6be605115

Comment: Thanks Levent, exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: This also helped me to convert +infinity to a comparable real number. Thank you!

Comment: @Oreo Interesting; +infinity as in the floating-point logic? I don't see how any other infinity is relevant in this context, but maybe you've something else in mind. (And I don't think `BV2Int` and `Int2BV` would work for floats.)

Comment: @alias Sorry I meant, the above links helped me find fpToReal, I couldn't find any other way to convert the infinity to compare it with a real type variable.

Comment: @Oreo Note that conversion from FP to Real is underspecified for NaN/Infinity inputs. That is, the conversion can *produce* any real as the output; so care is needed in such conversions. See here for details: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml It says: _All fp.to_* functions are unspecified for NaN and infinity input values.
  In addition, fp.to_ubv and fp.to_sbv are unspecified for finite number inputs
  that are out of range (which includes all negative numbers for fp.to_ubv)._